# Rails: Mapping root_url to an external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

We're using an external CMS to manage our site and I'd like to ensure that inside of our Rails app, root_url points out to that external url.  Is there any way we can do this?

Something like:

```
root :to => "http://wwww.example.com"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match the root of your application like this to redirect to an external URL

```
#
# config/routes.rb
#

root :to => redirect("http://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Digi_Cazter answered correctly you can do this by adding this

```
root :to => redirect("http://www.google.com/")
```

I would like to use such redirects from app only if I want specific url's to be redirected.

> I would suggest you to redirect the request directly form the
>   webserver you are using may be  apache-httpd or nginx or whichever you
>   may be using instead of passing it to app and then redirecting it.